In Azure Data Factory, stop pipeline run when False condition is complete
I want the Azure Data Factory pipeline to stop running when the False conditional statement is complete, but as this False condition is successful then it continues further to other steps. I do not want it to fail in order to stop. Is this possible?
How it works:
The IfCondition is nested in a ForEach activity, when this PL does not find files to process then it goes to the False conditional which just returns a message telling you which sources are not present. However, regardless of the True or False conditionals being successful, then it continuous to the following steps which take some extra minutes of running that I could save if it stopped right after prompting the message while False.



If you want to execute those activities which are available after if condition activity only, you can add those activities inside true part of if activity only.

If you want to stop the pipeline from running further after the False branch of the If Condition activity is executed, you can add all the activities that you want to execute after the IfCondition activity in the True branch of the If Condition activity itself.

This way, when the False branch of the If Condition activity is executed, the pipeline will stop running further, and the activities in the True branch of the If Condition activity will not be executed.

You can always do a dummy IF with the following condition:
@greater(div(100,length(activity('LOAD DATA').output.resultSets[0].rows)),0)
If there are no records, or JSON is empty - this will FAIL and will be rerouted to another WAIT 1s dummy block.
Otherwise if SUCCESS it will continue.

